# CSS is not importing Fonts and Image from Sub Folders

Tags: html, css

I am having issues linking my fonts and images to my CSS folder.

[image]

The fonts and images are kept in a sub-folder:

[image]

[image]

I am able to import link my images via my HTML

[image]

But it does not seem to work for CSS.

Comment: In your css you could use full http path/url or specify relative path from css location like ”./../fonts/Sensei-Medium.ttf”

Answer (score 0):

The base.css should be linking with `double dot` to out from `css folder` first, and goes into `fonts folder` to access the fonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Sensei";
  src: url("../fonts/Sensei-Medium.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("../fonts/Sensei-Medium.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Also the same principles to the images file on the `images folder`

```
html {
     background-image: url("../images/background.png");
}
```

See more documentation on:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image